# JIRA Board Plugin development

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I want to create custom JIRA board plugin.

Is this possible at all?

I went through https://developer.atlassian.com but I can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of addon types you can create for JIRA standalone:
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Plugin+Module+Types

I believe that you want to create a gadget for a JIRA board:
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS/Packaging+your+Gadget+as+an+Atlassian+Plugin